# sleep between every object in array in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want between every object in my array sleep or wait random time like php

```
sleep(rand(10,300));
```

then console.log it

`var array1 = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3'];`

like this

1. **msg1** 
   then wait 20 seconds
2. **msg2**
   then wait 30 seconds
3. **msg3**
   then wait 50 seconds

   i did try timeout but the problem is every 50 sec send the 3 objects 
   i want foreach object in array random time

mycode

```
var array1 = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3'];
array1.forEach(function(element) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(element);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: will you add some code what what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your environment supports `async/await` you could do:

```js
const time = 50 // base seconds
const randomTime = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * time * 1000) // miliseconds
const messages = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3']

function delayedMessage(msg, miliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(msg, miliseconds)
      resolve()
    }, miliseconds)
  })
}

async function logMessages(msgArr) {
  for (const index in msgArr) {
    await delayedMessage(messages[index], randomTime())
  }
}

logMessages(messages)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will call all `setTimeout` immediately. Instead, you could chain those calls, like so:

```js
var array1 = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3'];
console.log("Wait for it...");

(function loop(arr) {
     if (!arr.length) return; // all done!
     setTimeout(() => {
         console.log(arr[0]);
         // Only after having output this array value, proceed with the next timeout:
         loop(arr.slice(1));
     }, 500 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)); // Provide some randomness
})(array1); // Immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with a random `setTimeout`:

```js
const arr = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3'];

function loop(arr) {

  // Deconstruct the array into the first
  // element, and the rest
  const [head, ...tail] = arr;

  // if the array isn't empty
  if (head) {

    // Grab a random time between 1 and 10 seconds
    const time = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1) * 1000;
    console.log(head, time);

    // Call the function again with the remaining
    // array (tail), after `time`
    setTimeout(() => loop(tail), time);
  }
}

// Call `loop` with a copy of the array
loop([...arr]);
```